Days Syntax in Powerapps
'Days' in this code is invalid, is there something to replace the syntax of 'Days'
ClearCollect(
    DateCollection,
    ForAll(
        Sequence(Day(DateAdd(Today(), 1, Months)) - Day(Today())),
        {
            Date: DateAdd(DateAdd(Today(), -Day(Today()) + 1), Value, Days),
            Color: LookUp(CalendarEvents, EventDate = DateAdd(DateAdd(Today(), -Day(Today()) + 1), Value, Days), Color)
        }
    )
);

Basically I created an PowerApp where it collects selected data from the popup menu from the date picker and status list from tab list, after clicking save it goes to another page the SafetyCross page:
Collect(CalendarEvents, {
    EventDate: DatePickerCanvas1_1.SelectedDate,
    Status: StatusList.Selected.Value,
    Color: Switch(
        StatusList.Selected.Value,
        "Kein Ereignis/Unfall", ColorValue("#30D99B"),
        "Medizinische Behandlung", ColorValue("#F29F05")
        // more statuses will be added
    )
});

Navigate(SafetyCross);

From there I created 31 tiles that represents 31 days out of the month, based on what the user selects from the pop up menu it should reflect the color, so I choose Kein Erignis/Unfall it should show the corresponding ColorValue, but I'm having issues, what if I choose a different status for a different date. So here are the fill calendar Buttons;
LookUp(DateCollection, Date = DateValue("2024-06-01"), Color)

Safety Screen OnVisible 
ClearCollect(
    DateCollection,
    ForAll(
        Sequence(Day(DateAdd(Today(), 1, Months)) - Day(Today())),
        {
            Date: DateAdd(DateAdd(Today(), -Day(Today()) + 1), Value, Days),
            Color: LookUp(CalendarEvents, EventDate = DateAdd(DateAdd(Today(), -Day(Today()) + 1), Value, Days), Color)
        }
    )
);


You should use TimeUnit.Days (and TimeUnit.Months) in the third argument to the DateAdd function. See the function documentation for more details.
On a related note, this expression
Sequence(Day(DateAdd(Today(), 1, Months)) - Day(Today()))

Will always return an empty table, since the day of (today + 1 month) is the same as the day of (today), so that's equivalent to Sequence(0). If you want to have a sequence of days from (today) to (today + 1 month), you can use something like
Sequence(
  DateDiff(
    Today(),
    DateAdd( Today(), 1, TimeUnit.Months ),
    TimeUnit.Days
  )
)

You may need to add 1 if you want to include both today and the equivalent day of next month.
